# Mass on a stretch elastic string setup

Tags: classical-mechanics

Could anyone dispel my ignorance please.

I must be missing something obvious.

I'm not looking for the answer here, I just can't visualize the setup.

It says that W is attached at point C of an unstretched string where $AC = \frac{4a}{3}$

But the unstretched string is of length a (its natural length) so how can one attach W at four thirds of a?

Thanks,
Mitch.

[image]

Comment: doesn't lowercase a mean the radius of the bowl? If that's true then the units still don't make sense to me

Comment: Where does it say the natural length of the string is $a$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a$ is not the natural length; $a$ is the radius of your hemispherical bowl, so that $2a$ is the extended length. The point $C$ is $7/10$ of the way from $A$ to $B$, where the total distance from $A$ to $B$ is 
\begin{align}
d &= \frac{4a}{3} + \frac{4a}{7}\\
& = 4a \left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{7} \right)\\
& = 4a \left(\frac{7}{21} + \frac{3}{21} \right)\\
& = 4a \left(\frac{10}{21}\right).
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. John Hughes' answer makes sense as 7/10 times 4a(10/21)=4a/3. Thanks.